# Capture exit status from function in shell script

Tags: shell, exit

I have a very simple script.

test.sh

```
_EXECUTE_METHOD () {
  exit 1
}

_EXECUTE_METHOD
ERROR_CODE=$?
if [[ $ERROR_CODE -eq 1 ]]; then
  echo "Got error"
  exit 0
fi
```

This script terminate immediately when `exit 1` executed inside the function. I want to capture this exit status from function and handle it in the main script.

I have tried `set -e` & `set +e`, still no success. I can not use `return` statement.

Actual output:

```
$ sh test.sh 
$ echo $?
1
$
```

Actual output:

```
$ sh test.sh
Got error 
$ echo $?
0
$
```

Comment: "I can not use `return` statement." - Yes, you can! Just try it.

Comment: There's a `then` missing after the semicolon. Also, `[[` is nothing but a portability pitfall; `[` should be used.

Comment: @Jens It is possible even to resign from using `[` altogether. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650319/1174405)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `return` instead of `exit` inside the function:

```
_EXECUTE_METHOD () { return 1; }

_EXECUTE_METHOD || echo "Got error"
```

`exit` will terminate your current shell. If you have to use `exit` then put this function in a script or sub shell like this:

```
declare -fx _EXECUTE_METHOD
_EXECUTE_METHOD () { exit 1; }

_EXECUTE_METHOD || echo "Got error"
```

`(..)` will execute the function in a sub-shell hence `exit` will only terminate the sub-shell.

Comment: Sub-shell `(..)`, exit code capture `ERROR_CODE=$?` and Bash test `[[` seem to be [redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650319/1174405).

Comment: Agreed though more verbosity is needed sometimes for better understanding. Even `if..then..else` can be shortened as in the updated answer now.

Comment: Just commenting to say that I fell down a rabbit hole with the "declare" built-in. Being it an advanced topic, it would be great if you could add more info as to why it is needed

Answer (score 1):

No need for `[[` or `[`

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

_EXECUTE_METHOD () {
  return 1
}

if ! _EXECUTE_METHOD; then
  echo "Got error"
  exit 0
fi
```

or if you want to be concise:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

_EXECUTE_METHOD () {
  return 1
}

_EXECUTE_METHOD || { echo "Got error"; exit 0; }
```

Comment: never know this is possible in shell script. learn something new today